# How to display file last modification time on linux

Tags: c, linux, file, time

I want to write a C program to display the file last modification time in microsecond or millisecond. How could I do? Could you give me a help?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, Why do you need this?

Comment: @Alphaneo: In fact, I want to display all the files` last modification time in some directory. According to this, I can sort my files. thx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `stat()` function is used.  In sufficiently recent versions of glibc, `st_mtim` (note: no trailing `e`) is a field of type `struct timespec` that holds the file modification time:

```
struct stat st;

if (stat(filename, &st)) {
    perror(filename);
} else {
    printf("%s: mtime = %lld.%.9ld\n", filename, (long long)st.st_mtim.tv_sec, st.st_mtim.tv_nsec);
}
```

You should check for the presence of `st_mtim` in `struct stat` in your build system, and be ready to fall back to `st_mtime` (which has type `time_t`, and only 1 second resolution) if it is not present.

Comment: Thanks so much. It is wonderful. But the output is disorder, is it possible to sort them according to the file names?

Comment: @JavaMobile: Sure - put pointers to the filenames into an array and sort them, then run through that array and call `stat()`.

Answer (score 4):

You may use stat() function, it will return struct stat which contains time of last modification of a file. Here is the man page http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat. As to precision, it depends on whether your file system supports sub-second timestamps or not.

Comment: Is it possible to get time in Milli or Microsecond range using stat ... I am afraid not ;)

Comment: @Alphaneo: I looked at that Web page and it says that `stat` returns times with nanosecond precision.

Comment: Yes, stat() on Linux has extra fields to add nanosecond resolution, since kernel 2.5.48. However, as @ZelluX points out, accuracy != precision -- it really depends on what the filesystem supports.

Comment: @payne: I also use stat() function, but it seems to only display one file. I want to display the last modification time for all the files in some directory. How to do it?

Comment: @JavaMobile You can use getdents() or readdir() to get all the files in some directory.

Answer (score 1):

JFS, XFS, ext4, and Btrfs support nanosecond timestamps.

The book "The Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk has a good section on File attributes

Answer (score 1):

There is a stat command, which you can use directly

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/07/unix-stat-command-how-to-identify-file-attributes/

Comment: This answer is for a shell, but the OP asked for a C program.  Nevertheless, I found this question while looking for shell commands and stat(1) was just what I needed! :)

Answer (score 0):

To complete answers by **Andrew** and **ZelluX**.
The limitation is in file system. For Linux [ext3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext3) is commonly used, and you can see in wikipedia:

```
Date resolution   1s
```